Solr delete multiple synonyms at once in managed resources
How do I do a bulk delete of some synonyms in the Managed Resource Api.
I find it strange that the documentation only talk about about how to delete
synonyms one at a time. It will be quite sad if we cannot do a bulk delete.
Perhaps deleting all synonym terms is possible?
